# Android Notification Channel Description

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

Public method [`setDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setDescription(java.lang.String)) of the [`NotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel) class suppose to set the user visible description of this channel.

```
public void setDescription (String description)
```

Could anyone help me find where this description information is actually visible to user on his phone? Is this feature supported just by some versions of Android system? I have version 8.0 and I don't see that information listed anywhere.

Comment: Probably at `Settings->App->Notifications->Channels`.

Comment: @ADM - I don't see there any description, just name of channel

Answer (score 3):

The description is visible in the settings page of the notification channel. On Android 11 and 12 it is a greyed out section at the bottom of the page.

You can get there by opening `App info > Notifications` or `Settings > Apps & Notifications > Notifications > See all > Your app` and then clicking on the channel name.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaCQh.png)